# if statement never works in this code

Tags: javascript, html

The following function's `if` statement never executes even when i have filled both the text-field and the
 password field. The `alert` function works fine before the `if` statement but the `alert` function after the 
if statement never works.

Here is the function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckForMissingFields() {
        alert("before if statement");
        if(document.getElementById("username").length != 0 && document.getElementById("password").length != 0) {
            document.getElementByName("SignInButton").disabled = 'false';
            alert("inside if statement");
        }
        alert("outside if statement");
    }
```

Initially the state of the button `SignIn` is disabled. I look to enable it when the both the fields are done with. 
What could be the reason for `if` statement never working ?

Following is the corresponding HTML sign-in snippet :

```
<ul>  <form method="post" action="#">
          <li> <input type="text" id="username" value="Username or Email" size="25" name="UserID"  onfocus="emptyTextField()" /> </li>
          <li> <input type="password" id="password" value="password" size="25" name="UserPassword" onfocus="emptyPasswordField()" /> 
          <center><input type="submit" value="sign-in" style="font-size:20px" name="SignInButton" disabled="true"/> </center>
          </li>
              </form>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use: `if (document.getElementById("username").value.length)` etc. In other words, you'll need the `value` of the field.

No need for `!=0` by the way, if the `value.length === 0` `value.length` will evaluate to `false` (`falsy`)

Before checking the value length you may want to [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the value, so:

```
if (document.getElementById("username").value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'').length)
```

Comment: @PranayRana if there is trimming, it will. that's a different problem.

Comment: While there is no need for the `!=0`, there is nothing wrong with it either. And as a matter of fact, I do find that with it, you have more semantic code.

Comment: @Jasper: you're right, nothing wrong with it. Not sure if its really more semantic code with the comparison. Maybe you mean better readable? Anyway, using the comparison, I'd use `!==`.

Comment: @KooiInc, perhaps it isn't so much more semantic (or readable), but I was just noting that I feel that it is more semantic (or readable), showing there are arguments to do leave it in. You are of course right about strict checking.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementById` yields a DOM node. In your case an input field. It doesn't have a `length` property, but its `value` does.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to get the length of html tags. I think you want to get the contents of the input fields instead.

Like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("username").value.length != 0 && 
    document.getElementById("password").value.length != 0)
```

That answers the original question. Then, if you want a space to be considered as nothing, you should use a function that trims away spaces (like `jQuery.trim` ) before taking the length of the string.

Comment: @Pranay: define fail. This looks to me like exactly what OP was asking for. Of course we could hypothesise that perhaps OP also wants rounded corners on his sign in box, but this, as with spaces, would be outside of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
function trim(stringToTrim) {
    return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

just create function as above which trims space in string and than replace your if condition as below will do work for you..

```
    if(trim(document.getElementById("username").value) != "" && 
       trim(document.getElementById("password").value) != "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused: Where are you calling your

```
CheckForMissingFields()
```

function from? If you don't call that, you never will see the if statement work. Also, you'll need to re-evaluate each time the textboxes change, so try binding that function to the change event or blur event.

Comment: Presumably, calling it on submit would suffice. We know the first alert is shown, so invocation of the function is not an issue here.

Comment: He can't submit it though without calling that function. That function is what enables the submit button ( if I read that code right. ).

Comment: You're right, it probably isn't called upon submit, then, but regardless, we know that it *is* being called, and that that isn't the issue. The need to reevaluate still stands as a valid comment, tho.